# Correct way to model so that execution order is correct - Ansible

Tags: ansible

1. I wish to do 4 tasks on all machines in a group.
2. Once complete in **all** machines fully, task 5 must be run on one machine (Assume this is a DB instance).
3. Once *task 5* completes, tasks 6 to 10 are run on all machines in the same group.

Currently I am thinking of doing this as follows (solution #1) :

1. Playbook for Point 1
2. Wait until playbook 1 is done, then manually run Playbook for Point 2
3. Run Playbook for Point 3 after 2 is complete.

Another way (solution #2) is :

One playbook with 3 items - as follows :

`- hosts: groupA
  tasks: 1...4
- hosts: dbinstance
  tasks: 5
- hosts: groupA
  tasks: 6...10`

Can the SE community please help me verify the correctness of the above 2 approaches, and suggest better if any?

Answer (score 1):

You can use, `delegate_to` or `when: {{hostvars[inventory_hostname}} == "YOUR HOST"`

Comment: How do I ensure that when the task with `when:` clause is running, all other hosts in groupA are done & complete with 1...4 ?

Comment: @Zasz tasks are run in-order.

Comment: @tedder42 Yes, what you say is true on a given target machine. 

What I want is synchronization across target machines. If groupA has 20 machines, Only after all 20 machines complete 1-4, I want 5 to even start.

Comment: @zasz if you put 1-4 in one role and task 5 in another role, then call them in that order from a play, it'll work.

Comment: @Zasz This is how Ansible works by default. It will not go to the next task until all applicable hosts complete executing the current task.